# ubuntu rabbitmq - Error: unable to connect to node 'rabbit@somename: nodedown

Tags: django, rabbitmq

I am using celery for django which needs rabbitmq. Some 4 or 5 months back, it used to work well. I again tried using it for a new project and got below error for rabbitmq while listing queues.

```
Listing queues ...
Error: unable to connect to node 'rabbit@somename': nodedown
diagnostics:
- nodes and their ports on 'somename': [{rabbitmqctl23014,44910}]
- current node: 'rabbitmqctl23014@somename'
- current node home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- current node cookie hash: XfMxei3DuB8GOZUm1vdUsg==
```

Whats the solution? If there is no good solution, can I uninstall and reinstall rabbitmq ?

Answer (score 36):

I had installed rabbit as a service apparently and the

```
sudo rabbitmqctl force_reset
```

command was not working.

```
sudo service rabbitmq-server restart
```

Did exactly what I need.

P.S. I made sure I was the root user to do the previous command

```
sudo su
```

Comment: `service rabbitmq-server restart` +1.

Comment: Yes, you saved my day.

Answer (score 7):

if you need change hostname:

```
sudo aptitude remove rabbitmq-server
sudo rm -fr /var/lib/rabbitmq/
```

set new hostname:

```
hostname newhost
```

in file /etc/hostname set new value hostname

add to file /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 newhost
```

install rabbitmq:

```
sudo aptitude install rabbitmq-server
```

done

Answer (score 2):

Check if the server is running by using this command:

`sudo service rabbitmq-server status`

If it says

> Status of all running nodes...
>
> Node 'rabbit@ubuntu' with Pid 26995:
>
> running done.

It's running.

In my case, I accidentally ran the rabbitmqctl command with a different user and got the error you mentioned.

You might have installed it with root, try running

`sudo rabbitmqctl stop_app`

and see what the response is.

(If everything's fine, run
`sudo rabbitmqctl start_app`
afterwards).

Answer (score -2):

- Double check that your cookie hash file is the same
- Double check that your machine name (uname) is the same as the one stated in your configuration — this one can be tricky
- And double check that you start rabbitmq with the same user as the one you installed it. Just using 'sudo' won't do the trick.

Comment: How do you do any of these steps?

Comment: Yeah this isn't really an answer if it doesn't show how to do these things. May as well say "check that you know what you're doing".