# RabbitMQ: System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate

Tags: ubuntu, rabbitmq, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm starting to use ubuntu with WSL and, after installing RabbitMQ:

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server
```

[I try to start the server](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-rabbitmq-on-ubuntu-16-04-47) by doing:

```
sudo systemctl start rabbitmq-server.service
```

However I get the following error:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
```

I have tried to apply `sudo service start rabbitmq-server.service` as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52919706/5176549), but I get this error:

```
start: unrecognized service
```

furthermore, I restarted the computer following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52951542/5176549) with no success.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok solution finally found!

I just applied [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17731505/5176549) solution. It seems that from the pipenv the RabbitMQ didn't want to start a node.

Now by using the `sudo su` and restarting it worked:

```
sudo su
sudo service rabbitmq-server restart
```